# How can I get all API methods of a web api2 controller

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

If it was WCF Project,I usually see all avalible service methods by typing url

....some.svc/help

But in WEB API 2 how I get all such possible methods.

Comment: There is [route debugger](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger/). I am not sure if this is what you want, but it will show you all the routes in the service. If you need something similar for production, maybe [swagger](http://swagger.io/) is better option.

Comment: Check put the `ApiExplorer` class in web api2